# Create table of two user's AD groups

Tags: arrays, powershell, formatting

So I can't figure out how to get PowerShell to display a table to compare 2 user's AD group memberships.
The script doesn't have to do any comparison itself, simply display a table.  Username as heading, and the rows underneath being their respective groups.

All I've got so far is 2 variables containing the groups lists

```
Function Show-Groups ($usr1,$usr2)
{
   $groups1 = (((Get-ADUser $usr1 -Prop memberof).memberof) | Foreach-Object {(Get-ADGroup $_ -Prop samaccountname).samaccountname})
   $groups2 = (((Get-ADUser $usr2 -Prop memberof).memberof) | Foreach-Object {(Get-ADGroup $_ -Prop samaccountname).samaccountname})

   # Code to display in table?
}
```

I'm sure there's a clever way of doing this thought Format-Table, or creating a 2 dimensional array, or a hash table or something... I've played about with these the best I understand, but nothing that will output like:

```
SomeUser                    SomeOtherUser
--------                    -------------
Admin                       Underpaid
Document Readers            Document Readers
Document Writers            Remote Workers
Office Workers
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, tested successfully on PS2:

```powershell
Function Show-Groups ($usr1,$usr2)
{
    $groups1 = (((Get-ADUser $usr1 -Prop memberof).memberof) | Foreach-Object {(Get-ADGroup $_ -Prop samaccountname).samaccountname})
    $groups2 = (((Get-ADUser $usr2 -Prop memberof).memberof) | Foreach-Object {(Get-ADGroup $_ -Prop samaccountname).samaccountname})


    $arr=@()    
    $target1 = $groups1
    $target2 = $groups2
    if($groups2.Length -gt $groups1.Length)
    {
        $target1 = $groups2
        $target2 = $groups1
    }
    for($i= 0; $i -lt $target1.Length;$i++)
    { 
        $arr += , (New-Object pscustomobject -Property @{$usr1=$target1[$i];$usr2=$target2[$i]}) 
    }
    $arr
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect.  Thanks.
I was working on a pscustomobject approach, but hadn't got as far as it actually working.

Now I just need to look at your code and see what you did, otherwise I've learned nothing.
Thanks again!

Comment: great use of pscustomobject

Answer (score 2):

Not tested:

```
Function Show-Groups ($usr1,$usr2)
{
   $groups1 = (((Get-ADUser $usr1 -Prop memberof).memberof) | Foreach-Object {(Get-ADGroup $_ -Prop samaccountname).samaccountname})
   $groups2 = (((Get-ADUser $usr2 -Prop memberof).memberof) | Foreach-Object {(Get-ADGroup $_ -Prop samaccountname).samaccountname})

   $diff = $groups1.count - $groups2.count
   if ($diff -gt 0){$groups2 += ,''*$diff}
   else {$groups1 += ,''*-$diff}

   $i=0
   $groups1 | 
    foreach {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
     $Usr1 = $_
     $Usr2 = $groups2[$i++]
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input...

Unfortunately, this is resulting in: Name and Value headers, and rows alternating users and a group.   I can't seem to paste the output with formatting here.

Comment: Are you formatting the results of this function in someway? If i simply copy and Paste the code above from @Mjolinor and call it with `Show-Group test1 test2` i get a list of groups for each with the headings as Test1 and Test2.

Comment: Positive.
To double check, I ran a clean session. Copied mjolinor's code and pasted straight in, and called the function with 2 users

This is what I got when comparing 2 users.  (Image has been obfuscated as it's for a business).
This is using PowerShell v2.
[link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/5sz5a4b9r123kfo/AD.jpg

As you can see, the username alternates on the left, and AD groups (many of which are the same) are listed on the right